# SQL Subquery returns more than 1 value if else statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an if else statement which in either conditions returns more than one value or multiple rows:

The code below is what I have returns only 1 value.

```
 if @ifExist = 'TRUE' 
   begin   
     (SELECT [ID],[PersonFirstName],[PersonLastName],[PersonEmail] 
     FROM   MYTABLE
     WHERE  SOMEForigenID = SomeID)
   end

 ELSE 
   begin (SELECT [ID],[PersonFirstName],[PersonLastName],[PersonEmail] 
     FROM   MYTABLE
     WHERE  SOMEForigenID = SomeOtherID)
    end
```

I am not sure how to implement this so I can have it either return first select statement or second.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CASE` statement will help if you end up having more than two values for `@ifExist`.

```
SELECT [ID],[PersonFirstName],[PersonLastName],[PersonEmail] 
FROM   MYTABLE
WHERE  SOMEForigenID = CASE @ifExist WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

An example with multiple values:

```
WHERE  SOMEForigenID = CASE @ifExist 
                            WHEN 'A' THEN 1 
                            WHEN 'B' THEN 2 
                            WHEN 'Z' THEN 26 
                            ELSE -1
                       END
```

You can also use IIF if there are only two possible values

```
WHERE  SOMEForigenID = IIF(@ifExist, 1, 2) -- @ifExist is a BIT
```

or

```
WHERE  SOMEForigenID = IIF(@ifExist = 'TRUE', 1, 2) -- @ifExist as char
```

Comment: I tried this

        `SELECT [ID],[PersonFirstName],[PersonLastName],[PersonEmail] 
        FROM   MYTABLE
       WHERE  SOMEForigenID = CASE @@ifExist WHEN 'TRUE' THEN   @@first ELSE @@second END` it did not work still getting subquery returned more than 1 value.